# Orientdb - SQL query with millions of vertices causes Java OutOfMemory error

Tags: java, out-of-memory, orientdb

I need to create edges between all vertices of class V1 and all vertices of class V2. My classes have 2-3 million vertices each. A double for loop with a SELECT * FROM V1, SELECT * FROM V2 gives a Java OutOfMemory (heap space) error (see below). This is an offline process that will be performed once or twice if needed (not a frequent operation) as the graph will not be regularly updated by the users, only myself. 
How can I do it in batches (using SELECT...LIMIT or g.getvertices()) to avoid this?

Here's my code:

```
        OrientGraphNoTx G = MyOrientDBFactory.getNoTx();
        G.setUseLightweightEdges(false);
        G.declareIntent(new OIntentMassiveInsert());

        for (Vertex p1 : (Iterable<Vertex>) EG.command( new OCommandSQL("SELECT * FROM V1")).execute()) 
        {
            for (Vertex p2 : (Iterable<Vertex>) EG.command( new OCommandSQL("SELECT * FROM V2")).execute()) 
            {
                if (p1.getProperty("prop1")==p2.getProperty("prop1")
                {
                    //p1.addEdge("MyEdge", p2);
                    EG.command( new OCommandSQL("create edge MyEdge from" + p1.getId() +"to "+  p2.getId() + " retry 100") ).execute ();
                }
            }
        }
        G.shutdown();
```

---

OrientDB 2.1.5 with Java/Graph API

NetBeans 8.1 with VM options -Xmx4096m and -Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=7200

---

Error message in console:

> 2016-05-24 15:48:06:112 INFO  {db=MyDB} [TIP] Query 'SELECT * FROM
>   V1' returned a result set with more than 10000 records. Check if
>   you really need all these records, or reduce the resultset by using a
>   LIMIT to improve both performance and used RAM
>   [OProfilerStub]java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Dumping
>   heap to java_pid7896.hprof ...

Error message in Netbeans output

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OResponseProcessingException:
>   Exception during response processing.     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.throwSerializedException(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:443)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.handleStatus(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:398)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.beginResponse(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:282)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.beginResponse(OChannelBinaryAsynchClient.java:171)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.beginResponse(OStorageRemote.java:2166)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.command(OStorageRemote.java:1189)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemoteThread.command(OStorageRemoteThread.java:444)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:63)
>     at
>   com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphCommand.execute(OrientGraphCommand.java:49)
>     at xx.xxx.xxx.xx.MyEdge.(MyEdge.java:40)  at
>   xx.xxx.xxx.xx.GMain.main(GMain.java:60) Caused by:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: You could use Iterable<Vertex> v2=(Iterable<Vertex>) EG.command( new OCommandSQL("SELECT * FROM V2")).execute();
        for (Vertex p2 : V2) 
            {
                if ()
                {
                   
                }
            } to optimize your code

Comment: @AlessandroRota  Thank you for your tip, I did it and still have exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use code similar to the following

```
Iterable<Vertex> cv1= g.command( new OCommandSQL("SELECT count(*) FROM V1")).execute();
long counterv1=cv1.iterator().next().getProperty("count");

int[] ids=g.getRawGraph().getMetadata().getSchema().getClass("V1").getClusterIds();

long repeat=counterv1/10000;
long rest=counterv1-(repeat*10000);

List<Vertex> v1=new ArrayList<Vertex>();
int rid=0;
for(int i=0;i<repeat;i++){
    Iterable<Vertex> v= g.command( new OCommandSQL("SELECT * FROM V1 WHERE @rid >= " + ids[0] + ":" + rid  + " limit 10000")).execute();
    CollectionUtils.addAll(v1, v.iterator());
    rid=10000*(i+1);
}
if(rest>0){
    Iterable<Vertex> v=g.command( new OCommandSQL("SELECT * FROM V1 WHERE @rid >= " + ids[0] + ":" + rid + " limit "+ rest)).execute();
    CollectionUtils.addAll(v1, v.iterator());
}
```

Hope it helps.